# Centering an image and text together, inside a button, both horizontal and vertical

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm trying to build a button in pure CSS and fail spectacularly at aligning different elements. This is probably easy, but I can't get my head around it.
Here's how it should look:

[image]

The button should contain both text and an image. Both should be vertically centered. 
Both of them *together* should be horizontally centered.

I can get either of this to work on its own, but not both at the same time.

I'm really looking for some guidance as to what would be the *best* way of doing this, but here's what I'm using so far, as simplified as possible for me:

```
<span style="display:table; text-align:center;">
<span style="display:table-cell; position:relative; ">
    <a href=… >
        <img style="position:absolute; top:50%; margin-top:-#{ height / 2}px"></img>
    </a>
</span>
    <a href=… > TEXT </a>
</span>
```

And this is the current result.

[image]

Note how the icon should be further to the right, and the text should be a little further to the right as well. My current understanding is that right now it's dead center because using absolute alignment for the icon removes it from the flow.

(Some of the strange variables due to me generating the HTML via ERB.)

Comment: Post what you have so far.

Comment: I'm really looking for some guidance as to what would be the best way of doing this, but posted the code that takes care of proper vertical alignment for me. Thanks for the heads-up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use a `button` with some text an an image in it. Vertically align the contents of the button and add padding.

```
<button><span><img src="http://placehold.it/25x25">Some Text</span></button>​
```

```css
button{
    padding: 1em 2em;
}
img, span{
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/NRWU8/)

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't properly vertical-align the text in the button. Looking at your demo, it seems to be too high.

Comment: Wow, that's interesting. For me in Chrome your code looks like this: http://s10.postimage.org/pmvuy0emh/not_centered.png

Comment: @ludwigschubert I guess its browser dependant, how does this one look http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/NRWU8/2/

Comment: That actually looks very good! I can't get it to work with my code so far, though, working on it. With my code it breaks the image and the text in two lines.

Comment: Incredibly how long this took me. Your instructions were not to blame, however. ;-) Thanks man!

Comment: What if I have a button with fixed width and height?

Answer (score 0):

Did you search this HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .icon_button{
        background:#FFFFFF url(http://www.limitedlink.com/images/png/ico.png) no-repeat 4px 4px;
        padding:4px 4px 4px 22px;
        height:auto;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="halo" class="icon_button" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I looked at the HTML, and tried it, and fail to see how this applies to centering. All the paddings are hardcoded. Neither icon nor text is horizontally aligned. But thanks for your effort!

Comment: Please see after I editing my Javascript. I don't understand with you say "hardcoded", maybe you can explain me more.